# How to implement bug fix when working on long-lived Git branch?

Tags: git

I have a live, production website and I'm about to embark on adding a new feature to my website that will take a couple of weeks to implement.  If I have to make a sudden bug fix and deploy it to production, what is the proper Git workflow for doing that without interrupting work on the long-lived feature or having to push that incomplete feature's code to production?  Before I opened my website, I wouldn't have been concerned about any Git merge problems but now that I have a production site, I need to be very careful.

I have three web servers, "dev", "staging", and "prod" that map to my three main Git branches, "dev", "staging", and "master".  The staging and prod servers are configured identically.  All work is done on my dev server.  Note that I'm the only developer so I don't need to worry about merge conflicts with another developer.  Here's my current Git workflow:

```
# On my dev server, create a new feature branch off my dev branch.
git checkout -b new-feature dev
(Write and test new feature)
git add ...
git commit ...

# Merge new feature to staging branch, push to staging server, and test.
git checkout staging
git merge --no-ff new-feature
git push
(Test feature on staging server)

# Merge new feature to dev branch and push.  Dev now becomes the main
# branch for all future development.
git checkout dev
git merge --no-ff new-feature
git push

# Finally, merge the new feature now contained in dev into master and 
# push that new feature to production.  Note that I only ever merge 
# new features into production from the dev branch.
git check master
git merge --no-ff dev
git push
(Reload production server code and restart web server)
```

If I now have to fix a bug or perhaps implement a small one- or two-day feature without stopping work on the new feature that will take weeks to build, should I create a new fix-bug branch off my development branch, merge and push it to staging, merge and push it to dev, and then merge dev to master and push that to production as outlined above, and then go back and also merge fix-bug into my long-lived branch like the following?

```
git checkout long-lived
git merge --no-ff bug-fix
(Finish the long-lived new feature branch)

(Now repeat my usual workflow as described above)
git checkout staging
git merge --no-ff long-lived
git add ...
git commit ...
etc.
```

Is there a better "Git best practice" way to do this?  Is there anything I should watch out for?  I'm a Git "noob" so all suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do work - bug fix and development - on branches.  The main code line should normally be 'good to go' at any time, so the new feature should be on a separate branch from the master branch.  The bug report might or might not need a separate branch.  The branch is safe and simple; if you're sure you'll fix it in a single check-in, maybe working direct on maser is OK.

Comment: If your *feature* branch is not considered as **published**, do regular `git rebase fixes` on it.